# "Who has you doing that?"

Tags: grammaticality

"Who has you doing that?" Can you explain the grammatical structure, and correctness of this? To me, a native speaker, and teacher, it is perfectly acceptable. However a non native speaker, also a teacher, questioned the correctness of it. As explaining grammar can be a bit of a task, can anyone help?

Comment: The sixth definition of _have_ [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/have) has you covered, which is probably the way it is best explained, as a particular sense of _have_, using examples. By the way, questions here are expected to show their research. Take a look at [how to ask](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps edit your question, and, if there's a better answer, you'll likely get it.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute the interrogative pronoun "who" with the name of the subject, e.g. "Jeremy" then explain the [causative](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/causatives-have-get.html) "have/get" and you have:

> - Jeremy has you doing that (e.g fixing his roof).
> - Jeremy has you repairing his roof.
> - What do you say to a boss **who has you doing the work** for a position, but somehow won't actually give you the promotion? ([source](https://www.youbemom.com/forum/permalink/7296774/what-do-you-say-to-a-boss-who-has-you-doing-the-work-for-a-position))

You can use "get" equally as well while the verb that follows is in the infinitive.

> - Jeremy gets you to fix his roof
> - Who gets you to fix his roof?

From [Thought.Co](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-causative-verb-1689833)

> In English grammar, a causative verb is a verb used to indicate that some person or thing makes — or helps to make — something happen. Examples of causative verbs include *make*, *cause*, *allow*, *help*, ***have***, *enable*, *keep*, *hold*, *let*, *force*, and r*equire*, which can also be referred to as causal verbs or simply causatives.
>
> **A causative verb**, which can be in any tense, **is generally followed by** an object and **another verb form—often an infinitive or a participle** — and are used to describe something that happens because of a person, place, or thing whose actions bring about change in another entity.